# How to edit followUp interaction

Tags: discord.js

I am sending a `.followUp()` message with buttons, but after a button-interaction I can not edit the followUp message.

Is it possible to edit a followUp interaction, and if so... how?

Comment: It's probably better to add your current code.

Comment: That's gonna be too much code to tie together and add here. Plus it's not gonna make the question any clearer.

Answer (score 3):

No need for a complicated collector as @Azer154 suggested, because `followUp()` resolves with a `[Discord].Message` which has an edit method. Here's a code snippet:

```js
interaction.followUp("Followup message").then(msg => {
    msg.edit("Edited the followup message");
});
```

More information available in the [official documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/CommandInteraction?scrollTo=followUp).

Comment: Notice: this removes external emojis because `.edit` treats messages normally while functions like `.editReply` treats messages like webhooks / interactions. Not really sure of a workaround for this yet.